# How to keep a widget in PyQt5 cramming the screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

When I learned the `QHBoxLayout` and `QVBoxLayout` in `PyQt5`, I found it unable to use them with `QMainWindow`.They must lean on `QWidget`.Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow,QWidget,QLabel,QHBoxLayout,QVBoxLayout

class Example(QMainWindow) :
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.build_inter()

    def build_inter(self) :
        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,220)

        self.root_widget=QWidget(self)
        self.root_widget.resize(self.size())

        self.name_label=QLabel("Wang Suyu",self.root_widget)
        self.age_label=QLabel("14",self.root_widget)

        hbox=QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.name_label)
        hbox.addWidget(self.age_label)
        vbox=QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.root_widget.setLayout(vbox)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    example=Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, as a widget, I have no way to let `QWidget` automatically cram the screen as I change the size of screen with my mouse.The `root_widget` and two labels will just keep original.

How should I do? I really do NOT wanna change the super class of `Example`

Comment: You change the size of the screen with your mouse??

Comment: Ah it means to change the size of created window...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) is a special widget since it has default elements such as `QStatusBar`, `QToolBar`, etc. If you want to place a widget you should place a widget you must use the [`setCentralWidget()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) method.

[image]

In your case:

```
class Example(QMainWindow) :
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.build_inter()

    def build_inter(self) :
        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,220)

        self.root_widget=QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.root_widget)

        self.name_label=QLabel("Wang Suyu",self.root_widget)
        self.age_label=QLabel("14",self.root_widget)

        hbox=QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.name_label)
        hbox.addWidget(self.age_label)
        vbox=QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.root_widget.setLayout(vbox)
        self.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!(PS:Good picture)